# Using Session storage to store whether a popup has been shown

Tags: javascript, session

I have a website with a popup I built using plain HTML, CSS, and JS. Nothing fancy. I choose to display my popup after 15 seconds. Because I don't want to show the popup to anyone who's already seen it, I want to use session storage to store the fact I've displayed the popup.

I came up with this code:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    var today = new Date();
    var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0'); //January is 0!
    if (sessionStorage[mm+"_displayed"] != 'y'){
      var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
      modal.style.display = "block";
      sessionStorage[mm+"_displayed"] = 'y';
    }
  }, 15000);
```

The popup shows up after 15 seconds as expected. I can also see the session storage value in Chrome's Developer Tools. However I sometimes notice that the popup comes back up again.

- Is my comparison wrong?
- Is session storage specific to each tab? So far that's what I found but it seems counterintuitive. Sessions are shared across tabs so why wouldn't session storage be?
- Is local storage still "live forever"? I found a great [post on the topic and a workaround](https://www.sohamkamani.com/blog/javascript-localstorage-with-ttl-expiry/).

Thanks

Comment: session storage is specific to each memory session of the page. So the tab is the memory space and thus will be the only tab copy of that page able to view it. On the same tab? still there. Different tab? gone. The session is a unique view. Cookies are how you associate sessions across different views and join them into a single "session". Cookies are unique to a domain. Local Storage is... well local.

Answer (score 1):

[sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) is available for a tab in the browser. Use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) if you want to share data between browser tabs.

Also, note that since you are using `today.getMonth()`, the popup will be displayed once a month.

Comment: Yes I did that on purpose because I wanted to force the pop up after a month